# How to declare a C++ variable type based on platform?

Tags: c++, variables

I'm trying to write some C++ code that will work on both Windows and Linux.  I currently have this:

```
#ifdef WINDOWS
  HINSTANCE _handle;
#else
  void* _handle;
#endif
```

Is it possible to declare the type to be conditional based on the platform instead so that i could do something like:

```
#ifdef WINDOWS
  //define TYPE = HINSTANCE;
#else
  //define TYPE = void*;
#endif
TYPE _handle;
```

Comment: you should use typedef keyword. like `typedef HINSTANCE TYPE;`

Comment: `using TYPE = HINSTANCE;` is what you are probably looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
#ifdef WINDOWS
  typedef HINSTANCE TYPE;
#else
  typedef void* TYPE;
#endif

TYPE _handle;
```

Or, if you prefer `using` (altough in this context there is no difference):

```
#ifdef WINDOWS
  using TYPE = HINSTANCE;
#else
  using TYPE = void*;
#endif
```

Comment: Typedef is so last century, use ‘using’

Comment: @pm100 -- how is `using` superior to `typedef` in this context?

Comment: the syntax is clearer I think, I always have to double check I have my typedef the right way round. Certainly for more complicated things like function pointers its a no-brainer.